# How to only allow certain file extension on samba?

Tags: linux, samba, samba4

How to make samba only allowing certain file extension to put on for example i will only allow `.doc`, `.pdf`, `.exe` and it will block everything else.

I know we can use `veto files`, but `veto files` work with `blacklisting` certain file extenstion i found it not effective lets say we only allow 5 file extension but will block every other files extension, then i have to write a long list of other file extension.

So, I want to know if there is any `whitelisting` command so it will only allow certain file extension but will block everything else.